# Cannot import TensorFlow after installation using pip; TensorFlow missing in venv folder

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

I am currently facing an issue with installing and importing TensorFlow using pip within a virtual environment (venv). Despite successfully installing TensorFlow using the command **`pip install tensorflow`**, when I try to import it, it says that the module doesn't exist. I also cannot locate the TensorFlow package within the .venv\Lib\site-packagesfolder using the vscode explorer. However, when I navigate to the .venv\Lib\site-packages folder using the windows file explorer, I can see that TensorFlow is indeed present. Furthermore, both **`pip show tensorflow`** and **`pip list`** show that it is there.

This is the stack trace when trying to import it:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I tried using both the vscode terminal and windows command prompt to install the tensorflow folder but none of them have worked.

Comment: Are you shure that you have used the virtual environment to run your script?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the bug report, you should be using jupyter.

Click kernel displayed in the upper right corner to switch kernel to the environment where `tensorflow` is installed.

[image]